# Is there any benefit or detriment to picking up an opponent's Dynamo boost orb?

Tags: onrush

Friendly *Dynamo* class racers drop boost pickups for their team, which look like glowing blue balls/orbs.  Enemy Dynamo drops can still be collected as well, although they appear orange.

Is there a reason to grab or avoid these, beyond preventing the enemy team from being able to collect them?